# Same component, multiple times used - applying different css styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want box to get coloured but only the one i click on and the rest should have default one. Then, when i click on the next one the previous box should go back to the default color. Currently, when i click on one of them, all of the boxes get unwanted background color. I know that i basically pass "color" prop to each of them so all get coloured because of the same prop and state. But how to do it properly with only one state and without changing prop name?

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  const firstBox = () => {
    setColor("firstBox");
  };

  const secondBox = () => {
    setColor("secondBox");
  };

  const thirdBox = () => {
    setColor("thirdBox");
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Box setColor={firstBox} color={color} />
      <Box setColor={secondBox} color={color} />
      <Box setColor={thirdBox} color={color} />
    </div>
  );
}


const Box = ({ setColor, color }) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={setColor}
      className={`box  ${
        color === "firstBox" || color === "secondBox" || color === "thirdBox"
          ? "active"
          : ""
      } 
        `}
    ></div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this, but this is what I'd do:

```
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Box setColor={() => setColor('First Box')} selected={color === 'First Box'} />
 <Box setColor={() => setColor('Second Box')} selected={color === 'Second Box'} />
 <Box setColor={() => setColor('Third Box')} selected={color === 'Third Box'} />
    </div>
  );
}



const Box = ({ setColor, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={setColor}
      className={selected ? 'active box' : 'box'}
    />
  );
};


ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

Comment: There are definitely improvements to be made. For example, you could create an array that you call map on to render each Box element, you could rename the color prop to selected to add more semantic meaning, but the big thing here is lifting state up to the App component and not tracking too much state or info (like box name) in the box component itself.

Comment: change colour to selected, you might have forgotten to do that.

Comment: Hmm, after changing it to selected still does not work.

Comment: const Box = ({ setColor, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={setColor}
      className={selected ? 'active box' : 'box'}
    />
  );
};

Comment: Updated the solution to destructure the selected prop since I missed that. Also added the box className to both instances. Please copy/paste, it's working in my browser (my first iteration I cold-coded in browser, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked you didn't want to use any extra prop or state.
All you have to do is change your Box component code to this,

```
const Box = ({ setColor, color }) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={setColor}
      className={`box ${setColor.name === color ? "active" : ""}
        `}
    ></div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I do not have name prop on setColor.

Comment: setColor is a pointer to a function, and functions have name properties by default, so its not an extra prop